# как с помощью функций(map, filter, find, every, some, reduce, reduceRight, sort) манипулировать строкой(арифметические действия)

Tags: javascript

```js
let x = '10:25'
x=x.split(':')
let s1 = x[0],s2=x[1]
s2-=45
if(s2-45<0}{
s1--
}
let rez = s1+':'+s2
console.log(rez)
```

Есть строка разделённая с помощью split, нужно выполнить арифметическое действие на правой части а именно отнять от 45 чтобы получилось 10։0 и если значение правой стороны будет меньше 0, то от левой стороны отнимается -1, использовать date нельзя.

Comment: почему именно через эти функции? В них же нет вообще необходимости. Я же присылал Вам же вроде ответ как отнимать время без `Date` причём учитывая 24 часа, и если время будет меньше 00:00.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, проблема в том,что на сайте в котором эта задача, не принял ответ, говориться что нужно использовать split потом отнять число и на последок применить ещё одно условное действие и задача будит решена

Comment: Аааа, тестовая задача какая-то? То-есть надо использовать просто ещё какую-нибудь из перечисленных функций?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, да

Comment: @Denis640Kb, вот перевод с армянского։ "есть текст который показывает время, напишите функцию solution которая на входе получает X время и возвращает время которое было 45 минут назад" ну и ещё нужно использовать на сколько можно короткий код и использовать перечисленные функции

Comment: стоит еще ссылку на проверку добавить и в идеале пару тестовых случаев

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function solution(x){
    x = x.split(":"); //10:45  ["10","45"]
    let hour = +x[0]
    let min = +x[1];
     min-=45
     if(min<0){
         hour--
         min=60+min
     }
     if(hour<0){
         hour= 24+hour
     }
    return hour +":"+min
}
 console.log(solution("10:25"))
 console.log(solution("11:45"))
 console.log(solution("12:0"))
```

Comment: Это не рабочий код `min -= 145 => 9:-60 10:-40 11:-85`

Comment: Почему же?  В полне себе рабочий, даже сайт с задачей принял ответ как правильный

Comment: @VahanMuradyan я ведь пример привел, неужели не видно, если отнять время более часа - код не работает. Сайт скорее всего принял не код, а реализацию простых конструкций. Которая, в свою очередь, случайно выдала правильный ответ. И только потому, что сайт забил в проверку эти `45 мин`.

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg, согласен, но условием было, что нужно отнять только 45, вот потому и правильно вышло

Comment: @Vahan надо было на тот сайт запустить такой код `()=>"9:40"`. Сразу бы диплом дали, за самую эффективную реализацию :)